# Binary Classification with char/string features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Im currently working on a binary classification problem with proteins. The goal is to figure out whether or not a mutation will change the proteins function from active to inactive.
The mutation can happen at 4 different but fixed places in the amino acid chain that makes up the protein. So my feature vector consists of a char code of length 4, where each char represents the amino acid at one of the 4 places where a mutation takes place. In total there are 21 possible amino acids.

My question is how would I turn this string of 4 chars into something numerical for my classification.
What i tried so far is turning each cahr into the ASCII decimal representing the capital letter for that char (e.g. A->65) but this gave me only mediocre results.

I found something about one hot encoding but I don't know how to use it since besides the information about 4 of the total 21 amino acids occur in the mutation also the position at which they occur is important in my case.

This is a sample of the training data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my feature vector consists of a char code of length 4.. 
>   .. the position at which they occur is important in my case

Expand your four-character string into four one-character strings. This way there will be one feature per site (let's call them "S1", "S2", "S3" and "S4").

This way each protein site will be independent of other sites.

> how would I turn this string of 4 chars into something numerical for my classification.

Simply apply one-hot-encoding to each of those one-character features. Assuming you're working in Scikit-Learn environment, you could use `sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper` or `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer` to perform this mapping:

```
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
  (["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"], OneHotEncoder())
])
classifier = LogisticRegression()
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ("mapper", mapper),
  ("classifier", classifier)
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked quite fine already without tuning of the hyperparameters

Comment: If you want to investigate interactions between sites, then you may split the original four-character string into multiple two-character strings (eg. "S12", "S13", "S14", "S23", etc). Or once you feel more comfortable with Scikit-Learn, you can automate this process using the `PolynomialFeatures` transformer.

Comment: Can the `PolynomialFeatures` transformer work with non numeric data e.g. chars in my case? If not and I need to pass the one hot encoded features to the transformer wouldn't it be a bit senseless to use polynomial features as all the feature values are either 0 or 1 due to the one hot encoding and so all high order polynomials would be either 0 or 1.

Comment: You'd need to one-hot-encode strings before it's possible to apply `PolynomialFeatures`. But if you perform one-hot-encoding into "sparse results mode", then the large fraction of zeroes shouldn't become a (memory-) issue. Perhaps you could try inserting a feature selector in there somewhere (only testing interactions between significant mutations).